# Selecting two last available tables in Bigquery (when you don't have data on a daily basis)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the latest tables (two or more depending on the cases) but the problem is that we don't get data on a daily basis other wise I know that we can use the date range function.
I tried also this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY(dataset,
     "table_id CONTAINS 'tableprefix' 
     AND table_id IN ( SELECT table_id FROM dataset.__TABLES__ 
                       WHERE table_id CONTAINS 'tableprefix'
                       ORDER BY creation_time DESC LIMIT 2)")
```

It's working with LIMIT 1 (in this case we get the last available table) but it does not with LIMIT 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_QUERY(dataset, "(
  SELECT CONCAT(',', GROUP_CONCAT(table_id), ',')
  FROM (
    SELECT table_id FROM dataset.__TABLES_SUMMARY__ 
    WHERE table_id LIKE 'tableprefix%'
    ORDER BY creation_time  DESC LIMIT 2 
  )) CONTAINS CONCAT(',', table_id, ',')
")
```